# Why does tex4ht search for tfm files?

Tags: tex4ht

Can somebody explain me why `tex4ht` searches `tfm` files? What does it do with that `tfm` file?

At first I thought that it needs a `tfm` name, that it could find the `.enc` file
from `psfonts.map`. From `.enc` it could get all the glyph list. But if I create
a `foo.tfm` (empty file) it sees its wrong `tfm` header. Can it read bounding boxes of `tfm` glyphs? For what?

I'm trying to solve a common problem: `luatex` + `otf` + `tex4ht` = `html`

Comment: ps. I know about `.htf` fonts, that's why I thought that it will be enough to have  `.htf` and I'll not need `.tfm`.

Comment: for `luatex` + `otf` + `tex4ht`, see http://tug.org/pipermail/tex4ht/2013q2/000785.html

Comment: and http://michal-h21.github.io/fontspec/fontspec-4ht.html

Answer (score 6):

At its heart tex4ht is a dvi driver. So it uses TeX, tfm's and all and then converts the dvi to html rather than postscript or pdf.

Depending on the configuration mathematics and other "hard" items can be fully typeset and turned into images, but even if producing html text the TeX phase can need the correct tfm so that measurement is correct.

Comment: David, I know what is tex4ht. I'm more interested in `.tfm`. I understand that it's needed by TeX. But does it mean that I can replace it (not existing TFM) with any standard tfm and  just write a proper `.htf`?

Comment: @user31102 No the TeX phase needs TeX metrics  so it can make the dvi file. The htf files help the dvi driver handle specific font characters in html. If you are never making an image for maths you might be able to get away with substituting tfms for similar fonts but never tried.

Comment: With luatex I don't need tfm's, that and I need to replace otf font in DVI with "something". That something is any loaded font. And otf chars I can properly enter with \special commands (like html entities). But I still don't know about consequences.

Comment: @user31102 when tex4ht calls tex internally it will need 8bit tfms to make the dvi file, unless there has been a lot of unicode support added since I last looked (which was a long time ago)

Comment: Thanks David, a bit clearer. I think it needs tfm, when it creates .idv file.